# how can I create div at run time with specified css

Tags: css

I am creating a JSP page, I get data from database this data is divided into groups and has to be displayed in division tags according to its group.
My question is how to display divs in sequantial order from right to left, up to bottom  with same style dynamically? so I don't hava to specify the position of each div manualy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the div elements you're using have a fixed width and height, you can simply make them all `float: right` and they will naturally layout right to left and top to bottom.

Comment: the elements don't have a fixed size, and I used another layout to order them more effectively. thanx